# how to keep activity smooth when running animations

Tags: android, animation, out-of-memory

I have an app which shows images as frame animations each in its own separate activity but the animations are causing my app to fc with out of memory errors, although my animations work on there own just fine. I'm also calling start() from each activities on create method, which I understand is frowned upon, but the app will go through 5 or 6 of these animation activities before giving the out of memory error and I find after it crashes if I hit what ever button made it crash previously, it will miraculously work. I'm guessing its because its let go of resources just not sure the best way to approach this could anyone offer any insight? here is the code from the last activity and the activity that closes when called.

last activity .Java

package com.martinsapp.socialstories;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class TeethActivityBed extends Activity {
AnimationDrawable teethBrushing;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_bed_teeth);
    ImageView teeth_brushing_bed = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.teethImageView);
    teeth_brushing_bed.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.teeth_brushing_bed);
    teethBrushing = (AnimationDrawable) teeth_brushing_bed.getBackground();
    teethBrushing.stop();
    teethBrushing.start();

}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.teeth_activity_bed, menu);
    return true;
}
public void nextAct(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SleepingActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

}
```

last activity.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".TeethActivity"
android:background="@android:color/transparent">



<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:contentDescription="@string/teeth_bed_image"
    android:id="@+id/teethImageView"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@drawable/teeth_brushing_bed" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/teeth_bed_text"
    android:textSize="23sp"
    android:textStyle="bold|italic"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/next"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold|italic"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:onClick="nextAct"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

activity that closes .Java

```
package com.martinsapp.socialstories;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class SleepingActivity extends Activity {
AnimationDrawable sleep;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sleep);
    ImageView sleeping = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    sleeping.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.goodnight);
    sleep = (AnimationDrawable) sleeping.getBackground();
    sleep.stop();
    sleep.start();
}



public void nextImage2(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

activity that closes .xml

```
<RelativeLayout
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<ImageView

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:background="@drawable/goodnight"
    android:contentDescription="@string/wake_image"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />



<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:text="@string/sleepText"
    android:textSize="23sp"
    android:textStyle="bold|italic"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:gravity="center" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/finished"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:onClick="nextImage2"
    android:id="@+id/nextbutton"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @Vigbyor And what was the point in your edit? I understand if it were the new years thing I guess were passed that now but why remove the thanks?

Comment: Nice that you asked it. Welcome to Stack Overflow. http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/227860

Comment: Can you share some code? And make sure you are using images with proper size and not using Large Size images.

Comment: @Vigbyor thank you very much for the clarification I read all the info and now understand, thanks again

Comment: As I said the animations work on there own which makes me think the image sizes are okay (please correct me if this isn't the case) and sure I can add code but it would be for 4 or 5 activities.

Comment: Anybody? @Hardik Trivedi

Comment: @martinseal1987 : If you visit these two url 1) http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-development/frame-animation/ and http://www.edureka.in/blog/frameanimation-in-android-tutorial/ . You will find two different approach. Try that two. Whats the size of image you are animating and using as a frame ?

Comment: Hi I tried the second tutorial which has an implemtation of window focus changed but still same fc with out of memory error

Comment: Whats the size of image you are animating and using as a frame ?

Comment: There all slightly different ranging from 10kb to 50kb per slide, I ran the app on a budget single core Android netbook and it runs flawlessly

Comment: i solved this by scaling down an animation i found that was still large thanks for your help though